# How do I send a singular key press automatically?

Tags: autohotkey

Update 05.08.16 - 12:08 AM:
Here is a video of me trying to get this to work: https://youtu.be/h9gAirlUGyI

So, I'm trying to have a key pressed once on program launch.
This is what I have:

```
{
    Send, {F11}
}
```

Now when I launch the program it doesn't send the key.
Help?

Comment: Post a minimal example that reproduces the error please.

Comment: @IanB What exactly do you want? Enter a key when program FIRST starts, or EACH time it becomes active, or what? What does `F11` do in this context? Is it a one time thing? For instance, some programs have a nag screen that you need to dismiss (usually with `enter`). Then, the typical solution is to use a batch file (or even AHK script) to launch the program, and then send the key. The below answers are scripts that have to be RUNNING in order to work -- they don't work automatically. Otoh, if the script is run as part of the batch or ahk launching sequence, you are in business.  Lmk,

Comment: OKAY, @IanB, some of my questions are answered in your other post.  I have a comment there, and an answer below that shows how.

Answer (score 1):

```
flag = 0
processName := "xenia.exe"

Loop
{
    If ProcessExist(processName)
    {
        WinGetTitle, title, ahk_exe  %processName%
        IfWinActive, %title%
        {
            if flag = 0
            {
                Send, {F11}
                flag = 1
            }
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 0
        }
    }
    Sleep, 1000
}

ProcessExist(Name)
{
    Process,Exist,%Name%
    return Errorlevel
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do it for me, I've looked a bit more into things and I've now ended up with this code: http://pastebin.com/R2Etkkc9

It works and everything, if the window is minimized it appears and gets F11 sendt to it when I press Numpad 0. But that's not what I want, and I honestly can't find a way to make things happen on launch. I've tried loop, which does nothing on launch and a few other things. I'm really confused here.

Comment: check my edited answer, this will send F11 only if the window is in maximized state

Comment: But it starts windowed, what you're saying now is that I have to maximize it before F11 gets sent to the program, I could just have fullscreened the program myself then if I have to go up to the toolbar to maximize it.

Comment: sorry, what i meant to say is whenever the window is active, then F11 is send. I have checked the code, it works for me

Comment: what the code does is, if the specified program is opened then F11 is send once. and if you minimize it and later open it then the F11 is send again once. F11 is send once whenever the program comes active (sorry that i said "whenever maximized")

Comment: Please look at the video I've linked

Answer (score 0):

Per your other question and my comment there:

```
; This code both launches and fullscreens XENIA . . .
#Persistent
#SingleInstance, Force

Run, xenia.exe
Sleep, 500
GoSub, DoIt
return

numpad0::
GoSub, DoIt
return

DoIt:
IfWinExist, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass ahk_exe xenia.exe
{
    WinActivate, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass
    #IfWinActive, ahk_class XeniaWindowClass
    {
        Send, {F11}
    }
}
return
```

Now, if the question is REALLY about launching xenia with a file you've clicked on, e.g., using an explorer extension, there are ways of making it work (by adding the script to the registry and/or passing the file name and path into the command line.  Again, please give us details as to what you want to happen!

Comment: Please look at the video I linked to my question in the original post, hopefully that helps on what I'm trying to do